# Comment notifications by edit?

Tags: support, feature-request, comment

When starting a comment with @Username, the referred user gets a notification message (red flag in his postbox).

1) If not starting a comment with @Username, and subsequently editing it with @Username at beginning, does the referred user then get a notification?

2) If an initial @Username is removed by comment edit, does the notification vanish?

If answer is no, I would like to feature-request these two cases.

Comment: What feature are you requesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing showed that the information below is   partly incorrect. Editing  @ into a comment does not do anything.

Editing @username out of a comment will preserve the comment in the recipient's inbox, but remove the red inbox light.

---

The answers to such questions are subject to change without notice. Information available on  Meta ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197418/) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129973/); to a lesser extent [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/))  points to the following:

1. A notification will be generated if `@` was there at any point of time  (added later, or present initially and then removed).
2. Notification will also be generated if your comment is deleted. The user will get a snippet of the comment in the notification, but following the link they will find only the post under which the comment was.